# Would like to build a Nitrous.io Clone. Any suggestions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, virtualization, nitrousio, web-ide

I'm new to the world of coding and have found a great pleasure in it and would greatly enjoy pursuing it. My problem is 2 fold. 1st I work from many different devises ranging from Windows 8 Desktop, repurposed Linux laptop, and a Chromebook so starting on a project and being restrained to that one machine is a pain. 2nd I don't have a ton of money to invest in paying for Nitrous.io which I have found to be the exact solution that I am looking for, the problem being I can only have 1 box at a time otherwise I have to pay. I love the service but I just can't afford it right now.

What I would really like to do is roll my own Nitrous.io. With my student status there are some services such as AWS that I get for free. This is where I would like to host my clone. I've fairly technically savvy, I'm a systems admin by day, but not so savvy (yet) when it comes to coding.

My question is does anyone have any suggestions on where I could start bringing this to fruition? I don't want to launch VM's b/c the lack of power of my Chromebook I just want to launch a virtual workspace exactly like Nitrous.io does has configured. I know you use to be able to clone Cloud9 but the version you can get is fairly outdated. Are there any other IDEs that I could get working like Nitrous?

Comment: Are you asking about suggestions for building your own Nitrous.io-like app, or suggestions for already-existing apps that are similar to Nitrous.io but allow you to have more than one box for free?

Comment: I'm asking for suggestions or directions to move to roll my own environment using already available IDE tools and resources. I want my own personal dev environment that I can take anywhere I want and work from anywhere I want without restrictions to just one project. Ideally what I would like is to use 'Atom' as my editor and just a standard Linux terminal. Instead of having to remote into a desktop and having that reliability compromised by the connection I just want web framework or virtual application only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to coding, then you will simply not be able to take on a project of this size.  Even an advanced programmer would probably not take on a project like this on their own.

Instead, I would encourage you to look at the wealth of free, cross-platform desktop IDE's which are available.

[Eclipse IDE](https://eclipse.org/) is very popular and is actually a framework with extensions to support many languages.  It's written in Java, and runs on all major platforms.

[Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) is similar in some ways in that it's written in Java, it's cross platform, and it supports a lot of languages.

[CodeLite](http://codelite.org/) looks like a promising alternative if you want something a little lighter weight.  It looks like it might have a more similar look and feel to Nitrous.io.

I have known people who use [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/).

There are a surprising number of [free, cross-platform integrated development environments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments) that will do the same job of Nitrous.io but locally.  Of course, you will have to sync the machines to work on the same projects across your various machines, but there are also lots of great, free tools for that ([Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/), for example).

My advice would be to start by installing one at a time and using it for a while until you find one that you like.  Your first instinct to want to rewrite Nitrous is understandable, but nearly impossible.  A better idea is to try to find an alternative that you can use for free.

Comment: Thank you for the response and I understand what I am asking isn't going to be easy but that wasn't really my question. What I would like to know is how one would go about attempting it. If there was a direction I could move in. Eclipse, Netbeans, and CodeLite are all geared around languages that I have little if any interest in learning. I'm focusing primarily on Web Dev (Ruby on Rails, CSS, HTML, & JavaScript). Nitrous.io is the perfect solution for development, however, not for learning, I'm actively working on many projects between personal and online courses. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: If the goal is to develop an IDE for these languages, I would suggest looking into contributing to the existing efforts to build such environments using the Eclipse platform.  Aptana and RadRails2 are such efforts for Ruby and Rails, for example.  If you want a place to start, contribute to an existing open source project.